# How can I combine multiple case values in a match statement?

Tags: python, match, case

For example, if I want to accomplish this:

```
match value :
    case 2 :
    case 3 :
    case 5 :
    case 7 :
    case 11 :
    case 13 :
    case 17 :
    case 19 :
        print('It is prime!')
    case default :
        print('It is not prime')
```

but by doing something like this:

```
match value :
    case 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 :
        print('It is prime!')
    case default :
        print('It is not prime')
```

The references I've read don't seem to have this type of combination operation. Thoughts?

Comment: please tag the language, is this python?

Comment: if yes, syntax for 3.10+ is here, search "case" - https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html   - in particular :  `case 401 | 403 | 404:`

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a Python forum. Yes, Python 3.10. And thanks!

Comment: Nope, all languages.  It might help to read the tour - https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
match value :
    case 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11, | 13 | 17 | 19 :
        print('It is prime!')
    case default :
        print('It is not prime')
```